# Haskell LLVM binding Ambiguous Type

Tags: haskell, llvm, ffi

I am trying to get started with the LLVM binding for Haskell.  A great place to start is Hello  World.

The following is from a blog by the author of the binding.

```
bldGreet :: CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
bldGreet = do
    puts <- newNamedFunction ExternalLinkage "puts" :: TFunction (Ptr Word8 -> IO Word32)
    greetz <- createStringNul "Hello, World!"
    func <- createFunction ExternalLinkage $ do
      tmp <- getElementPtr greetz (0::Word32, (0::Word32, ()))
      call puts tmp -- Throw away return value.
      ret ()
    return func
```

It does not compile.
Instead I get "Ambiguous type variable `n0' in the constraint:
  (type-level-0.2.4:Data.TypeLevel.Num.Sets.NatI n0)
    arising from a use of`getElementPtr0'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)"

Here is a variation that does work

```
llvmModule :: TFunction (IO Word32)
llvmModule = 
    withStringNul "Hello world!" $ \s -> do 
    puts <- newNamedFunction ExternalLinkage "puts" :: TFunction (Ptr Word8 -> IO Word32)
    main <- newNamedFunction ExternalLinkage "main" :: TFunction (IO Word32)
    defineFunction main $ do
      tmp <- getElementPtr0 s (0::Word32, ())
      _ <- call puts tmp
      ret (0::Word32)
    return main
```

The first seems more natural.  The question I have is what is the ambiguity in the first, and how do I fix it.  The second question I have is why is the second not ambiguous.

Comment: could it be a typo and forgot the 0? getElementPtr0<- ? I am just guessing here.

Comment: No.  There are two different functions.  getElementPtr0 uses a default, where getElementPtr does not -- hence the extra argument.  Also, the error is, I am pretty sure, a typeclass thing.  It(GHC) wants me to tell it something more specific about the typeclass.  I just have not figured out what it wants.

Comment: Maybe http://hpaste.org/ the complete thing so the pro's can fiddle with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.  So I solved the problem.  It is indeed a typeclass thing.  And it has only confused me more.  However, I do have an answer to the solution.  But do feel free to help my understanding out.  First, some digging.  The function createStringNul has type

```
createString :: String -> TGlobal (Array n Word8)
```

Fine.  The problem the compiler was having is that the "n" in the Array type is ambiguous.  It could literally be anything in the world.  Lookup, Array, and you see

```
newtype Array n a
```

Now it is not so obvious, but upon a little digging, in particular wrt the call to getElementPtr, one finds that the n, really should be a Nat n, which is a type-level way to fix the size of the array.  Now, the definition of Array n a, does not actually care it is really just a type synonym for [a].  So you can use D0, or D9 or whatever you want from the 
Data.TypeLevel.Num.Reps
package.  Fixing the size of the array, while a good idea was not actually taken into consideration by this function.  But anyways, changing 
    greetz <- createStringNul "Hello, World!"
to 
    greetz <- createStringNul "Hello, World!" :: TGlobal (Array D0 Word8)
works.

Here is the interesting part...  I did not expect it to work.  D0 is supposed to be 0, so I did not understand why it was allowing me to store so many characters in a 0 size "Array"  However, if you look at the source code, it is immediately clear that the type restriction is not actually payed attention to.

Fine, whatever, upon compiling one realizes that the createStringNul is deprecated, and withStringNul is preferred instead.  Except I don't completely understand how withStringNul's types work.

Answer (score 1):

`createStringNul` [is marked as deprecated](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/llvm/3.0.1.0/doc/html/src/LLVM-Core-CodeGen.html#createStringNul) in the current version of `llvm` (3.0.1.0). Use `withStringNul`:

```
import Data.Word
import LLVM.Core

bldGreet :: CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
bldGreet = do
    puts <- newNamedFunction ExternalLinkage "puts" :: TFunction (Ptr Word8 -> IO Word32)
    func <- withStringNul "Hello, World!" $ \greetz ->
      createFunction ExternalLinkage $ do
        tmp <- getElementPtr greetz (0::Word32, (0::Word32, ()))
        _ <- call puts tmp -- Throw away return value.
        ret ()
    return func
```

As to what causes the error in the first example, it's related to the fact that `withStringNul` has a more informative type: `withStringNul :: String -> (forall n . Nat n => Global (Array n Word8) -> a) -> a` -- cf. to `createStringNul :: String -> TGlobal (Array n Word8)`. The function argument of `withStringNul` has a [higher-rank type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types) - it means that the function works for all `n` where `n` is a natural number.

If you really want to use `createStringNul`, you can make the first example compile by adding an explicit type signature for `greetz`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
module Test
       where

import Data.Word
import Data.TypeLevel.Num.Reps
import LLVM.Core

bldGreet :: CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
bldGreet = do
    puts <- newNamedFunction ExternalLinkage "puts" :: TFunction (Ptr Word8 -> IO Word32)
    greetz <- createStringNul "Hello, World!"
    func <- createFunction ExternalLinkage $ do
      tmp <- getElementPtr (greetz :: Global (Array (D1 :* D3) Word8)) (0::Word32, (0::Word32, ()))
      call puts tmp -- Throw away return value.
      ret ()
    return func
```

The `:*` type constructor [comes from the type-level package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/type-level/0.2.4/doc/html/Data-TypeLevel-Num-Reps.html#t%3a%3a-42-) and is used to construct type-level numbers. `D1 :* D3` means that the array has size 13.

Comment: It appears you posted just after I did.  I had figured out essentially what you said.  However, the problem is that to use the function withStringNul ... the second argument must be the entire CodeGenModule that is being constructed.  If feels quite unnatural to use.

Comment: @ArmUser The function argument of `withStringNul` has type `(forall n . Nat n => Global (Array n Word8) -> a)`. Its return type is `a`, which can be any type - not necessarily `CodeGenModule`. `CodeGenModule` in the type of `createFunction` is the monadic computation context. `createFunction` itself returns a `Function` - but since you can't create a function outside a module, `createFunction` runs inside a `CodeGenModule` monad.

Comment: @ArmUser In general, this is a quite natural Haskell idiom. Cf. with [`withFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v:withFile) in `System.IO`.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov Great, so here is a version that compiles with the llvm-3.2.0.2 package: https://gist.github.com/robstewart57/7194104 . My question is: how can this be extended so that `bldGreet` instead takes a String, and prints it after "Hello", e.g. "Hello Joe!". Something like `bldGreet :: CodeGenModule (Function (String -> IO ()))` . How would I extend `bldGreet` to do this?

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov I should add.. if you can concoct this slightly modified `bldGreet`, I next ask how you would pass the string "Joe" as an argument to `bldGreet` in the `main` function of my GitHub gist..

Comment: @RobStewart Something like the following should work (not tested): https://gist.github.com/23Skidoo/7195530

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov perfect, thanks. Yes it compiles, and behaves as I would have expected.